# the difference between subsequent sibling combinator (~ )and child selector (>) in css

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have been reading about CSS the last couple of days, and searched the internet for this question.

Could anyone please explain me whats the difference between (~) and (>)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

General sibling means the element is *after* another element, where the child selector targets elements that are *directly inside* of certain elements.

Siblings:

HTML:

```
<div class="brother"></div>
<div class="sister"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.brother ~ .sister {
    /* This styles .sister elements that follow .brother elements */
}
```

Children:

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent > .child{
    /* This styles .child element that is the direct child of the parent element;
    It will not style the .child element that is the child of .child */
}
```

Comment: Note that sibling combinators can only match *following* siblings, so for example if you have a `.sister` before a `.brother`, `.brother ~ .sister` won't match it.

Comment: @BoltClock Good catch, I left that detail out, I'll update my post now.

Comment: Hmm, "immediately follow" - that would be the `+` (adjacent sibling) combinator. `~` matches any following siblings in the same parent.

Comment: Still not clear, What if the parent-child example had another <div class="child"> after the immediate child. How would the difference be for the two selectors?

Answer (score 0):

Some examples are shown below to show how the CSS selectors are used...
Example:

```
div>p
```

The above, selects all p elements where the parent is a div element
Example:

```
p~ul
```

The above, selects every ul element that are proceeded by a p element